# Mathematica as a report generator

Tags: dynamic

I would like to use Mathematica as a kind of report generator.

I'm working in a Mathematica notebook and I want to handle Mathematica like this:

1) I want to define one cell as a text cell. In this cell I want to integrate an expression (maybe as an inline cell) lets say a*b (a and b have been defined in an input cell before).

2) After evaluating this cell a*b should be replaced by (assume a=10 and b=5) 50, so that the resulting cell would look like this.

> some text ....... 50.. some other text......

More general: I want to have the possibility to call a function or an expression (which has been defined before) in a text cell. The displayed result of the call should be updated, whenever I change the input values.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to @Rojo's here's a more detailed explanation:

```
total = Dynamic[x + y]
```

Define the variable total that dynamically sums x and y

```
x = 10;
y = 5;
```

Now create a text cell by right clicking on the cell bracket at the right and choose style Text. I Type:

```
When I count the value x plus y I get: total
```

Now double click on total and right click and choose Create Inline Cell.
A background color will appear on the word total. Now double click again again on the word total , right click, and choose Evaluate in Place.

The TEXT cell now changed to:

```
When I count the value x plus y I get: 15
```

Every time x or y changes your text cell adjust the correct value

Answer (score 10):

How about using `TextCell`?

```
computation = 1 + 2;
TextCell[StringJoin@{"And the result is ", ToString@computation, 
   " according to the computation."}, "Section"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course other styles can be also used instead of `"Section"`.
You can even make it dynamic, and then you don't have to evaluate the `TextCell` again:

```
Dynamic@TextCell[
  StringJoin@{"And the result is ", ToString@computation, 
    " according to the computation."}, "Section"]
```

Any subsequent calls updating `computation` updates the `TextCell` as well.

Comment: Congrats on 5K :P

Comment: @Rojo: 5K? Where? :)

Comment: I could have swooorn

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly you want to run a `Dynamic[a*b]` in an inline cell and evaluate it in place